# Get Angle with respect to 360 degree

Tags: unity, c#, mathematics

I have fixed object, around its an object is moving in circular shape. Now i am willing to get my moving object angle with respect to fixed boject like form 0 to 360. How can i do this.

[image]

i tried this code snippet

```
Vector3 targetDirection = camHead.transform.position - transform.position;
            angle = Vector3.Angle(targetDirection, transform.forward);
```

But it is not giving what i need. Sorry i am null in vector math and trigonometry, a trick will be prefer with explanation.

Comment: Use transform.up instead

Comment: what, where, how?

Comment: Instead of transform.foward in your code

Comment: @mohammad-faizan-khan : It's very disappointing to make efforts to help other and not getting any feedback. If you don't do it for the ones who answer you, do it at least for future readers.

Comment: @Hellium, you make a good point, but rest assured that in such situations, a clear lack of quality is noticed by the system. Enough poor quality questions, and a user simply won't be allowed to ask more questions. I will be back to up-vote your answer, when I have my votes replenished.

Answer (score 3):

@kolenda is right, but his answer is incomplete.

Here is an utility function to have a signed angle (using `atan` inside this function would have been possible). You will have to provide a normal vector in order to be able to know the sign of the angle :

```
public static float SignedAngle( Vector3 from, Vector3 to, Vector3 normal )
{
    // angle in [0,180]
    float angle = Vector3.Angle( from, to );
    float sign = Mathf.Sign( Vector3.Dot( normal, Vector3.Cross( from, to ) ) );
    return angle * sign;
}
```

Be "careful", this function will return the angle between -180 and 180, not 0 and 360 (just add 180 to the result)

Answer (score 2):

Use [Mathf.Atan2](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Atan2.html)

In general atan2 is an extension of typical arctan function which gives you the correct result in all 4 quarters of a circle, so you don't need to use if's with arctan to compute the angle. You just pass two params - X and Y of your direction vector and you get the angle in Radians.

Comment: did you understand the question completely. i suspect that it will not work

Comment: You've provided a 2D image with 2D description so yes, I think I understood your question. I just assumed you'll be able to use this simple function for your needs, instead of waiting for the code to just copy and paste. Countless people used this function, including myself but you "suspect" it won't work... Have you looked at the link at least?

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan, why do you *suspect* it does not work? Your lack of explanation, and the fact that you *suspect* but did not *attempt to disprove* leads me to think you may not simply *understand* this answer, to a degree; which is perfectly fine, provided you provide *constructive* feedback. Perhaps this answer could be improved, to make it easier to understand?

Comment: I don't understand this answer at all, but I put it in my code and it worked lol. Nothing else did.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Mathf.Atan2 like this and then clamp:

```
return Clamp0360(Mathf.Atan2(movingPos.y - fixedPos.y, movingPos.x - fixedPos.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg)
```

and Clamp0360 function:

```
public static float Clamp0360(float eulerAngles)
{
    float result = eulerAngles - Mathf.CeilToInt(eulerAngles / 360f) * 360f;
    if (result < 0)
    {
        result += 360f;
    }

    return result;
}
```

But one notice: in my approach, degree will grow counterclockwise, but not like on your picture, when you have grow in clockwise.